# Adding a Windows 7 machine to a Windows 2000 peer-to-peer network (through hub)

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-2000

We have three Windows 2000 machines talking through a hub, and we are trying to upgrade so we bought a Windows 7 machine to add to the network.  All of the Win2K machines can access the public directory on the Windows 7 machine, but the Windows 7 machine cannot access the other Win2K machines -- we just keep getting a pop-up asking for network user name and password.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See this...http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/windows-7-cannot-connect-to-newtork-drive/

Comment: Thank you.  This has worked for one of my machines (the Win7 machine can now access one of the Win2K machines)  I will try to see what the problem is with the other 2 win2K machines.

Comment: The fix listed in the link from Moab has Worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your Windows Policy Editor for network/security settings.  As I recall there's a setting in Windows 7 to allow compatibility with older versions of Windows, but in order to get this you have to lower the security requirements.

If you're behind a firewall, then this isn't a big deal unless the general public are able to connect their laptops to the inside of your network (e.g., your company is a public library).

If you don't have a firewall, then a router such as one of the LinkSys wireless/broadband routers can provide NAT for you, and you should seriously consider getting one of these.

Comment: I have NO experience with Windows 7.  We have no firewall.  (All computers are connected with ethernet cables to a hub [not a switch])

Comment: Might be better to have a switch, they tend to be more intelligent when it comes to networking, just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 Professional and Ultimate:

1. Open the Administrative Tools in the Control Panel in your Windows 7 (NOT the network drive server)
2. Open the Local Security Policy
3. Select the Security Option under Local Policies
4. Choose Send LM & NTLM responses in Network security: LAN
   manager authentication level

.
[image]

.

For Windows 7 Home Users:

you can edit the registry yourself by doing this:

1) open Notepad:

2) copy this text and past in notepad:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa]
>   “lmcompatibilitylevel”=dword:00000002

3) save the file on your desktop (or anywhere else) as name.reg – “.reg” is important.

4) run the file and press yes on the 2 poppups.

Now it should be fixed.

.

Alternate method for Home version

For Windows 7 HOME PREMIUM:

1. Click “Start” on lower left of screen.
2. Click “Run” in the menu.
3. Type regedit then click “Ok”.
4. User Account Control warning may pop up – click “Yes”
5. Find folder “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE” double click on it
6. Now on the same left side below the folder you clicked on find “SYSTEM”
   and double click on it.
7. Now on the same left side below the folder you clicked on find
   “CurretControlSet” and double click on it.
8. Now on the same left side below the folder you clicked on find “CONTROL”
   and double click on it.
9. Now on the same left side below the folder you clicked on find “Lsa” and
   RIGHT CLICK ON THE Lsa folder.
10. Scroll down to “New” then select “DWORD (32-bit) Value”
11. The new item appears to the right of the folders you have been clicking on.
    The name is highlighted as “New Value #1″

Change the name to LMCompatibilityLevel

12. Now RIGHT click on it “LMCompatibilityLevel” Then select “Modify”
13. Change the “Value data” from 0 to 1 then click “Ok”
14. At top right click on “File” then “Exit”
15. You are finished, and it should work.

.

NOTE:  If your network drive host is a Windows 2000 server, you may need to upgrade it to SP4.

.

[Source of Information](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/windows-7-cannot-connect-to-newtork-drive/)

.